# Angular 4 Form FormArray Add a Button to add or delete a form input row

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-forms

I am building an app using Angular 4.0.2. How can I add a button to a form to add a new row of input and a delete button for a particular row to delete? I mean that I want a form something like this. I want my form to look something like this:

[image: Form Image].

Here is my code:

add-invoice.component.html

```
    <h3 class="page-header">Add Invoice</h3>
    <form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">
      <div formArrayName="itemRows">
        <div *ngFor="let itemrow of itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <h4>Invoice Row #{{ i + 1 }}</h4>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Item Name</label>
            <input formControlName="itemname" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input formControlName="itemqty" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Unit Cost</label>
             <input formControlName="itemrate" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Tax</label>
            <input formControlName="itemtax" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input formControlName="amount" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <button *ngIf="i > 1" (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="addNewRow()" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Row</button>
    </form>
    <p>{{invoiceForm.value | json}}</p>
```

Here is my code for add-invoice.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormArray, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-invoice',
  templateUrl: './add-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-invoice.component.css']
})

export class AddInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  invoiceForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm(){
    this.invoiceForm = this._fb.group({
      itemRows: this._fb.array([])
    });
    this.invoiceForm.setControl('itemRows', this._fb.array([]));
  }

  get itemRows(): FormArray {
    return this.invoiceForm.get('itemRows') as FormArray;
  }

  addNewRow(){
    this.itemRows.push(this._fb.group(itemrow));
  }

  ngOnInit(){

  }
}
```

Comment: Code please, What have you tried?

Comment: I have been reading reactive forms docs on angular.io But nothing is working can you code it for me please.

Comment: I could, but this is not a coding service, you need to show us your effort.

Comment: Okk please wait I provide you

Comment: Please wait 10-15 minutes I'll compile and show you.

Comment: @AJT_82 Here's my code

Comment: I'll take a look :)

Comment: I will be really thankful to you @AJT_82 Very much very very Thanks

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here's a shortened version of your code:

When you init your form, you can add one empty formgroup inside your formArray:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.invoiceForm = this._fb.group({
    itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
  });
}

get formArr() {
  return this.invoiceForm.get('itemRows') as FormArray;
}
```

Then the function:

```ts
initItemRows() {
  return this._fb.group({
    // list all your form controls here, which belongs to your form array
    itemname: ['']
  });
}
```

Here is the `addNewRow` and `deleteRow` functions:

```ts
addNewRow() {
  this.formArr.push(this.initItemRows());
}

deleteRow(index: number) {
  this.formArr.removeAt(index);
}
```

Your form should look like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="invoiceForm">
  <div formArrayName="itemRows">
    <div *ngFor="let itemrow of formArr.controls; let i=index"  [formGroupName]="i">
      <h4>Invoice Row #{{ i + 1 }}</h4>
      <div>
        <label>Item Name</label>
        <input formControlName="itemname">
      </div>
      <button type="button" (click)="deleteRow(i)" *ngIf="formArr.controls.length > 1" >
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" (click)="addNewRow()">Add new Row</button>
</form>
```

Here's a

### [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h3tmfe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Is there any way to do this in template-driven form.

Comment: In this case I would though suggest you use model-driven form, it is much cleaner this way in my opinion.

Comment: I am posting another question just now. Please help me on that also. I will be really thankful to you.

Comment: Sure, I can take a look :)

Comment: It was just a going through the button. Bro, I am really thankful to you for this answer. I will surely buy you a beer when my first Salary will come. By the way, please go through http://stackoverflow.com/q/43528200/7882245

Comment: Can you explain a little about what's going on in the code? I am not getting it.

Comment: don't forget to call `formArray.markAsDirty()` in order to make the form dirty

Comment: @AJT_82 please suggest me any solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50550246/initialize-form-array-with-existing-array-in-angular-reactive-form/50550296#50550296

Comment: @AJT_82 I am hanged in a position like this. wondering if you can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50798049/angular-4-add-dynamic-row-and-get-data-in-controller

Comment: @AJT_82 thank you for this answer. I am stuck in one problem that how I can get value from an input of any particular index.Is there any way to fetch the value of desired input