# Angular5/4+: Populate nested ReactiveForm using API call

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I am trying to populate nested `ReactiveForm` which is split into several child form components. Once the API request is completed I am able to populate parent form but cannot loop child `FormArray` exactly to the count of child data. Below are the snippets from my code:

**Edit View: edit.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: Service = new Service({
            id: '',
            title: '',
            description: '',
            service_extras: []
        });    
  public routeParams: any = {};    
  constructor ( 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: ServicesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setRouteParams();
  }

  setRouteParams() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.routeParams = params;
      // getting services using api call
        this.getService(this.routeParams);
    });
  }

  getService(params) {
    this.service
    .getService(params.id)
    .subscribe((service: Service) => {
        this.data = service;
    });
  }

}
```

I am requesting data in base `edit.component.ts` component and passing the data received to the parent form component which is child of `EditComponent`

**edit.component.html**

```
<service-form [serviceFormData]="data"></service-form>
```

**service-form.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'service-form',
    templateUrl: './service-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./service-form.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceFormComponent implements OnInit {

    private _serviceFormData = new BehaviorSubject<Service>(null);    
    @Input()
    set serviceFormData(value) {
        this._serviceFormData.next(value);
    }        
    get serviceFormData() {
        return this._serviceFormData.getValue();
    }    
    public service: Service;
    public serviceForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {    
        this.serviceForm = this.toFormGroup();
        this._serviceFormData.subscribe(data => {
            this.serviceForm.patchValue(data);
        });
    }

    private toFormGroup(): FormGroup {           
        const formGroup = this.fb.group({
            id: [ '' ],
            title: [ '' ],
            description: [ '' ]
        });    
        return formGroup;
    }
}
```

I have here receiving data with the help of `@Input` var by subscribing to its changes and then patching value to the form, now everything works fine upto this as all the fields gets filled once the data is received. Problem is here below:

**service-extra.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'service-extra-form',
  templateUrl: './service-extra.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./service-extra.component.scss']
})
export class ServiceExtraComponent implements OnInit {    
  private _extraFormData = new BehaviorSubject<ServiceExtra[]>([]);

  @Input() serviceForm: FormGroup;    
  @Input() 
  set extraFormData(value: ServiceExtra[]) {
    this._extraFormData.next(value);
  }    
  get extraFormData() {
    return this._extraFormData.getValue();
  }

  public extrasForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.serviceForm.addControl('service_extras', new FormArray([]));    
    this._extraFormData.subscribe(data => {
      this.addNew();
      this.extras.patchValue(data);
    });

  }

  private toFormGroup()
  {
    const formGroup = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      service_id: [''],
      title: ['']
    });    
    return formGroup;
  }

  public addNew()
  {
    this.extrasForm = this.toFormGroup();        (<FormArray>this.serviceForm.controls.service_extras).push(this.extrasForm);
  }

  public removeThis(i: number)
  {
    (<FormArray>this.serviceForm.controls.service_extras).removeAt(i);
  }


  get extras(): FormArray {
     return this.serviceForm.get('service_extras') as FormArray;
  }

}
```

Above `ngOnInit` code does nothing but adds the single extras form (even if there are two records) and populate that form, this case is same even if I remove subscribe part and only use `this.addNew()`. How do I know how many records are there for `ServiceExtras` so that I can add that much `FormGroups` to `FormArray`.

**Edit 1**

Stackblitz [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqzcov)

**Edit 2**

Issue is if there are two records coming from API for service extra then I am not able to generate two `FormGroups` and populate them with data, Because at the time of rendering I cannot detect how many records are coming for service extras from API.

Comment: Can you demonstrate your issue on stackblitz?

Comment: @yurzui I have edited my question to add Stackblitz demo

Comment: Check the code, but I still didn't understand what is the problem. WHEN do you to know how many records are there for ServiceExtras?

Comment: Do you want this counting?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aTsX4pwRkLTntGJUWNhvpRlFqrTru12T/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @trungk18 actually the issue is if their are 2 records coming for service extra then it is populating only one and this happening because I am pushing 1 form group to the `service_extra` `<FormArray>`... My problem is I cannot detect how many service_extra records are coming from API so that I can generate those many `FormGroups` and and push is to `<FromArray>service_extras`, makes sense?

Comment: so you want print this in addnew function?

Comment: You can get count of field like below:
console.log(this.serviceForm.value.service_extras.length+1);

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue, please read my edit 2.

Comment: @SagarGuhe
please check this link may be helpful to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520010/angular-4-form-formarray-add-a-button-to-add-or-delete-a-form-input-row

Comment: @dgpoo buddy if you have seen my Stackblitz demo then you would know I have already achieved this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fix ( stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mwys5m) )

Explanation of the problematic behavior :

Your input is declared this way :

```
<service-extra-form [serviceForm]="serviceForm" [extraFormData]="serviceForm.value.service_extra"></service-extra-form>
```

So the input is the value of the form, not the value from the api.

But as you populate your form after an async call to the api, the first value "sent" to  `ServiceExtraComponent` is `undefined` and in the `ServiceExtraComponent` `ngOnInit` you call

```
this.addNew();
this.extras.patchValue(data);
```

with `data = undefined`

It creates a new formGroup in the formArray, then patch with undefined.

So when the API responds your form is already created with a formArray containing one item, so the `patchValue` truncate your service_extra array to match your form.

A correction could be to bind the return of the API directly as `ServiceExtraComponent` `Input` aka :

```
<service-extra-form [serviceForm]="serviceForm" [extraFormData]="serviceFormData.service_extras"></service-extra-form>
```

Comment: the solution is working for me, also the solution provided by @Yerkon is working fine. I am now confused which to mark as accepted and to which award a bounty. I really appreciate your valuable inputs

Comment: Take yerkon's. 

Answer (score 2):

In `service-form.component.html`, you bind `serviceForm.value.service_extras` property to   `extraFormData`. But before `service-extra-form` component initialized `serviceForm` doesn't have **service_extras** formArray. And after init. of  `service-extra-form` component, you call `addRow()` method which fill form with one row exactly:

**service-extra.component.ts**:

```
 ngOnInit()
  {
    this.serviceForm.addControl('service_extras', new FormArray([]));    
    this._extraFormData.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('service_extra_data', data);
      this.addNew();
      this.extras.patchValue(data);
    });

  }
```

**service-form.component.html:**

```
<service-extra-form [serviceForm]="serviceForm" 
                    [extraFormData]="serviceForm.value.service_extras">
 </service-extra-form>
```

Passing [serviceForm] to `service-extra-form` is sufficent. Why you pass `serviceForm.value.service_extras`, if you already pass `form`?

### Fix, removing extra сodes. Do the same with less code

**ServiceExtraComponent**:

```
export class ServiceExtraComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() serviceForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() extraFormData: ServiceExtra[];

  public extrasForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

 ngOnChanges(data) {
    //console.log('ngOnChanges', data);

    // if changes only extraFormData
    if (data.extraFormData) {
      this.extras.setValue([]); // reset
      let newExtraArr = data.extraFormData.currentValue;

      for (let i = 0; i < newExtraArr.length; i++) {
        this.addNew();
        this.extras.patchValue(newExtraArr);
      }
    }
  } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceForm.addControl('service_extras', new FormArray([]));
  }
```

`@Input() extraFormData: ServiceExtra[];` here pass `extra_data` from **api** and on `ngOnChanges` lyfecycle hook, resetting serviceForm's `service_extras` `formArray`

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-populate-nested-reactiveform-using-api-call)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will take a look at the answer and let you know.

Comment: the solution is working for me, also the solution provided by @PierreMallet is working fine. I am now confused which to mark as accepted and to which award a bounty. Really appreciate your valuable inputs

Comment: @SagarGuhe, glad to help✌