# Angular 2 How to remove file from files of input type file multiple?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

How to remove specific file from files selected with input type with multiple attribute?

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" #fileInput multiple>
```

[image]

I want to delete one of the selected file.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

https://jsfiddle.net/Sagokharche/eL3eg6k4/

Comment: please, post and `onFileChange()` code

Comment: There is nothing inside onFileChange function yet. @OnnaB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need it to be impossible to choose? Then use [HTML Input file accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) property. `accept="image/png"` for instance.

Or you want it to filter from the input *after the user selected it*?
Then you should use a custom directive or check for the file types in the ts code upon upload.

EDIT
in that case, in your code:

```
onFileChange(event) {
    const fileList = event.target.files;
    console.log("User selected fileList:", fileList)
    Array.from(fileList).filter(
      item => {
        console.log("file mime type:", item['type'])
      })

    const filesToUpload = Array.from(fileList).filter(
      item => { return item['type'] != "application/zip" })

    console.log("reduced list:", filesToUpload)
  }
```

[Working stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-idvmdr).

Comment: I want to filter it after user selected it.

Comment: How we can remove it from actual input type file? Please see the screenshot which shows 2 files and after delete one file from filelist it should show 1.

Comment: @ForestG I have a question please, How to post this file in ws? I have a similar example and my file post null in ws: `urlSearchParams.append('files', this.files)` this is my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942899/no-files-were-uploaded-using-api Thanks

Comment: I do not understand. The code I provide shows that the filtered data only contains specific file types. You can continue to use that array and your files are "deleted" from it. You can bind that again with the [ngModel](https://angular.io/guide/user-input) bind back if you want, but that totally makes no sense from a UserExperience point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the inputs FileList-object in .ts side like this:

```
onFileChange(event) {
    console.log(event.srcElement.files);
}
```

Edit:
If you are looking for a solution how to make dynamic form (add and delete inputs), then have a look at this answer and demo:
[Angular 4 Form FormArray Add a Button to add or delete a form input row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520010/angular-4-form-formarray-add-a-button-to-add-or-delete-a-form-input-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I want to delete file from srcElement.files but not on onFileChange. I want to do it delete button click, in that case i will not get event.

Comment: @SagarKharche Updated answer with a link to a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In your hmtl code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 productAddfromImages" *ngFor='let url of imageurls; let i = index'>
      <img class="img-fluid" [src]="url.base64String">
      <a (click)="removeImage(i)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Remove</a>
    </div>
    

  </div>
```

Remove function

```
  removeImage(i) {
     this.imageurls.splice(i, 1);
  }
```

Add Function

```
onSelectFile(event) {
if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
  var filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imageurls.push({ base64String: event.target.result, });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[i]);
   }
   }
  }
 }
```

For more details:https://findandsolve.com/articles/how-to-upload-and-remove-multiple-image-using-anular-code-example