# Multi Dynamic Reactive Forms Angular 5 Nested Input Fields

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am having some trouble with creating a Multi Dynamic input fields on A Reactive Angular 5 Form.

I was using this [answer but I needed to expand on it for my scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521492)

### Here is a working Example of the App

[Stackblitz New Window](https://angular-tmyj5r.stackblitz.io/)

[Stackblitz CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmyj5r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

#### Code Excerpt

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="item_quantity"> Quantity </label>
   <input type="number" min="1" (ngModelChange)="onChanges($event)" formControlName="item_quantity" class="form-control" id="item_quantity">
</div>

<div class="form-group" style=" border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px;">
    Repeat these input based on the item_quantity from above <br>
    <input type="text" name="item_details" formControlName="item_details.item_detail" class="form-control">
</div>
```

#### Question 1

I need to repeat the `item_details` input based on the `item_quantity` for every row that the user Creates

#### Question 2

Can I be able to allow file uploads like this

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="item_image"> Item Image </label>
   <input type="file" formControlName="item_image" class="form-control" id="item_image">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you heard about formArray in reactive forms? Create n numbers of formControl inside the formArray depending upon your selected Quantity.

Comment: Did you find any answer to this ? if so please update.