# How to create new section, onclick of new button in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a section with 3 fields, when click on new button, i must get the same section. I get no errors, so i am not getting where i am going wrong

[Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ve3szr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML:

```
     <form *ngFor="let emergency of Emergencies; let i = index">
        <div>
          <label > Name</label>
  <input type="text"   [(ngModel)]="emergency.Name" name="emergency.Name" 
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label >Phone</label>
          <input type="text" OnlyNumber="true" [(ngModel)]="emergency.Phone" name="emergency.Phone"
            maxlength="15" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label >Relations</label>
          <select class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"[(ngModel)]="emergency.ship">
            <option >{{ship.Description}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: There are Alot of errors in your code, check console as well

Comment: is it fine if you do it with template forms using `NgModel`, since u r using `ngModel` also.

Comment: @Sravan i guess that can be done, but is it possible to keep formgroup as wel and do

Comment: you can use either `template driven` or `reactive` at once, if you need to do with form group check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520010/angular-4-form-formarray-add-a-button-to-add-or-delete-a-form-input-row) as suggested in one answer, I ll add an anwer and logic how to do using `ngModel`

Comment: ya please you add me an answer, let me check with that link as wel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can use `template driven` forms here is an answer for you.

Add a button for creating a new field

```
<button (click)="addEmergency()">New</button>
```

Now, add `addEmergency` method in component:

```
addEmergency() {
    var item = {
      "ContactName":"Person3",
      "Phone": "122355",
      "relationship": ""
      }
    this.Emergencies.push(item);
  }
```

**In html:**

```
<div  *ngFor="let Emergency of Emergencies">
  Your inputs go here
</div>
```

[**Here is a demo I created out from your code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3hampn)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FormArray to create dynamic fileds.

Go through this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520010/angular-4-form-formarray-add-a-button-to-add-or-delete-a-form-input-row) or [blog](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/)