# Not able to store dynamic FormArray in FormGroup

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6, formarray

I have a FormGroup which has three FormControl fields and one FormArray fields as shown in the figure below. The requirement is to take the manager name from user and once add button is pressed, manager details should be displayed in table. In table a remove button is provided, when remove button is pressed manager should be removed form the table and list. When the form is submitted list of managers should be saved. Everything works fine except formArray logic.

[image]

I tried to find a solution to this online (followed various links:- https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/, 
[Angular 4 Form FormArray Add a Button to add or delete a form input row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520010/angular-4-form-formarray-add-a-button-to-add-or-delete-a-form-input-row)), but did not helped much. There is not much material on how to store formArray in formGroup. Please suggest.

Below is my code, please have a look:-

**1. manager-create-modal.component.html**

```
<div>
    <form [formGroup]="createForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormCreation()">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="column">
               <div class="form-inline">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="remote_access_method">Remote Access Method: <font color="orange"> *</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                      <input type="text" size='38' class="form-control" formControlName="remote_access_method" >
                 </div>
                </div>
               <br>
               <div class="form-inline">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="status">Current Status: <font color="orange"> *</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                    <input type="text" size='38' class="form-control" formControlName="status">
                 </div>
               </div>
               <br>
               <div class="form-inline">
                 <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="secregid">Registration ID:<font color="orange"> *</font> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                   <input type="text" size='38' class="form-control" formControlName="secregid">
                 </div>
               </div>
               <br><br>
               <div class="form-inline">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <br><br>
                    <div formArrayName="manager_formArray">
                      Enter name: <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="MgrName" size='50' >&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="addPM()">Add</button>
                        <br><br>
                        <table class="table table-hover">
                          <tr><th>#</th><th>Manager Name</th><th>Remove</th></tr>
                          <tr *ngFor="let pm of createForm.get('manager_formArray').value; let id = index">
                              <td>{{id+1}}</td>
                              <td>{{pm.MgrName}}</td>
                              <td>
                                <span class="table-remove">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="removeMgr(id)">Remove</button>
                                </span>
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
              </div>
              <br>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**2. manager-create-modal.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-manager-create-modal',
      templateUrl: './manager-create-modal.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./manager-create-modal.component.css']
    })
    export class ManagerCreateModalComponent implements OnInit {

      createForm: FormGroup;
      manager_formArray: FormArray;
      remote_access_method: FormControl;
      status: FormControl;
      secregid: FormControl;

      constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

      createFormControls(){
        this.remote_access_method = new FormControl('');
        this.status = new FormControl('');
        this.secregid  = new FormControl('');
        this.manager_formArray = new FormArray([ this.createItem() ]);
      }

      createItem(): FormGroup {
          return this.formBuilder.group({
            MgrName: ''
          });
      }

      createFormVariables(){
          this.createForm = new FormGroup({
            remote_access_method  : this.remote_access_method,
            status  : this.status,
            secregid   : this.secregid,
            manager_formArray: this.manager_formArray,
          })
      }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.createFormControls();
          this.createFormVariables();
      }

      addPM(mgr: any): void {
          console.log("inside addPM");
          this.manager_formArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({MgrName:''}));
          console.log("list after addition:"+this.manager_formArray.value);

          for(let i = 0; i < this.manager_formArray.length; i++) {
             console.log(this.manager_formArray.at(i).value);
          }
      }

      get managerFormArray() {
       return this.manager_formArray.get('MgrName') as FormArray;
     }

     onFormCreation(){
       console.log("success")
     }
    }
```

The manager name is not displayed in the table and I keep on getting below error:-

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'manager_formArray ->
>   MgrName'          at _throwError (forms.js:1731)          at setUpControl
>   (forms.js:1639)           at
>   FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl
>   (forms.js:4456)           at
>   FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl
>   (forms.js:4961)           at
>   FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges
>   (forms.js:4911)           at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:9031)
>             at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:10299)             at
>   checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:10261)            at debugCheckAndUpdateNode
>   (core.js:10894)           at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:10854)       inside
>   addPM         manager-create-modal.component.ts:50 list after
>   addition:[object Object],[object Object]
>         manager-create-modal.component.ts:53 {MgrName: ""}
>         manager-create-modal.component.ts:53 {MgrName: ""}

I even don't understand why elements are not getting added to manager_formArray. Please help me out.

Comment: you forget [formGroupName]="i" in < tr *ngFor="let pm of createForm.get('manager_formArray'); let id = index" **[formGroupName]="i"** >

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks Eliseo, but I am still getting the same error..

Comment: Do you get the error when you press the Add button? Are you able to console.log everything inside the `addPM`-method?

Comment: You are creating many `FormGroup`s using the same key on each controller inside it , `MgrName`. I am not sure if that is a problem or not, bout you could try to use different keys each time you create a `FormGroup`, maybe adding the `id` to the name? I am not sure if this matters though. Just a thought

Comment: @John I do not get error when Add button is pressed. It navigates to addPM() method but nothing gets added to the manager_formArray. Get following console.log messages:- 

inside addPM
manager-create-modal.component.ts:50 list after addition:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
manager-create-modal.component.ts:53 {MgrName: ""}
manager-create-modal.component.ts:53 {MgrName: ""}
manager-create-modal.component.ts:53 {MgrName: ""}

Comment: @John Sorry, I did not got what you are suggesting regarding keys. Could you please elaborate. You can also copy paste the code to your controller and check the error if you want. Just create a controller with name manager-create-modal.component and copy paste my code in HTML and TS file. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues. First of all, it is better to move the Input which adds more `FormGroup`s to your `FormArray` outside of the `<div formArrayName="manager_formArray">`- element. I created a new FormControl `this.mgrNameInput = new FormControl('');` for this reason (see [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzujbe) for more details).

You also need to add the message to the new entry when you press the `Add`-button, calling the `addPM()`-method:

```
addPM(){ // removed the argument, using the controller inside the method instead.
    this.manager_formArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({MgrName:this.mgrNameInput.value}));
    this.mgrNameInput.reset(); // reset the input field.
}
```

I also added the remove-method when removing an entry.

```
removeMgr(index: number){
    this.manager_formArray.removeAt(index);
}
```

Please check the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzujbe) for the complete example

Comment: Thank you so much !! The managers are getting added to the manager_formArray successfully. I was trying to do everything on one formArray variable did not thought of using another formControl variable as you did.

Comment: One more thing please - How to clear Enter name: input box once Add button is pressed? The input box is not getting cleared.

Comment: Add `this.mgrNameInput.reset();` to the bottom of the `addPm()`-method

Comment: I have accepted the answer. It will be eligible for award bounty after 21 hrs. Will reward once enabled.