# Angular How to Add/Remove from Array of FormGroups

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a list of replies under a post using *ngFor.  This is set up using an array of formGroups.  The replies can be updated, created, or deleted by the user.  When I edit a reply, I get a response back from the API and use the following code to update the array.

```
//This is a simplified response from the API
updatedReply = {
  "id": "dajlajg",
  "content": "test"
}

//Find the existing entry and remove it from the existing reply list
this.replyBuilder = this.replyFeedbackForm.value.replies.filter(reply => reply.id !== replyId)

//Add the updated reply back into the list of existing replies
this.replyBuilder = this.replyBuilder.concat(updatedReply)

//Update the value and the view
this.repliesControl.patchValue(this.replyBuilder)
```

After running code similar to the above, the updated reply contents will display in the view immediately.  No problem.

With adding and deleting replies, I follow a similar process for each, but the patchValue does not end up with a similar result.  When a reply is added, patchValue does not cause the view to update at all.  When a reply is deleted, patchValue overwrites the deleted reply with the reply last in the list of replies.

```
//Add Reply
newPost = {
  "id": "dahljal",
  "content": "test reply"
}
//When I test this line, I can see it does add the new reply with all the old replies
this.replyBuilder = this.replyFeedbackForm.value.replies.concat(newPost)

this.repliesControl.patchValue(this.replyBuilder)


//Delete Reply
 this.replyBuilder = this.replyFeedbackForm.value.replies.filter(reply => reply.id !== replyId)
this.repliesControl.patchValue(this.replyBuilder)
```

Could anyone help me understand what I should be doing to update the view after adding and deleting replies when using an array of formGroups?

Comment: You'll probably want to look into FormArrays: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: This should help you getting started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43521492/6294072 I think you actually are trying to use a FormArray, correct? It just looks a bit wrong...

Comment: I have a complete working example here that adds/removes FormGroups from a FormArray: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/tree/master/APM

Comment: You can refer this http://keepnote.cc/code/form-group-with-formarray-adding-dyamic-row-angular-5-6