# ngFor giving error 'Identifier is not defined __type does not contain such a member'

Tags: html, angular

I have implemented a sub-component in which the user can dynamically add and remove a set of controls to and from a collection. The solution was based on the answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43520010/angular-4-form-formarray-add-a-button-to-add-or-delete-a-form-input-row).

It compiles and works like a charm but there is an annoying message on the *ngFor directive that says:

> Identifier 'sections' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a
>   member Angular

**I am using VS Code as my IDE.**

I have seen similar errors on *ngIf directives and the message goes away when you add a double exclamation point (!!) at the beginning of the condition statement but in this case the directive is using a collection not a Boolean value.

How can I make this eyesore go away?

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="saveForm">
  <label for="sections" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Sections:</label>

  <div class="col-md-9">
      <a class="add-link" (click)="addSection()">Add Section</a>

      <div formArrayName="sections">
        <!-- The "problem" seems to be "saveForm.controls.sections" -->
        <div *ngFor="let section of saveForm.controls.sections.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
          <label for="from">From:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="from">
          <label for="to">To:</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="to">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

And this is the component:

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ISection } from '../shared/practice.model';

@Component({
  selector: '[formGroup] app-sections',
  templateUrl: './sections.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sections.component.scss']
})
export class SectionsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() sections: ISection[];
  saveForm: FormGroup;

  get sectionsArr(): FormArray {
    return this.saveForm.get('sections') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private controlContainer: ControlContainer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.saveForm = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
    this.saveForm.addControl('sections', this.formBuilder.array([this.initSections()]));

    this.sectionsArr.clear();

    this.sections.forEach(s => {
      this.sectionsArr.push(this.formBuilder.group({
        from: s.from,
        to: s.to
      }));
    });
  }

  initSections(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      from: [''],
      to: ['']
    });
  }

  addSection(): void {
    this.sectionsArr.push(this.initSections());
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try :         `<div *ngFor="let section of saveForm?.controls.sections?.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">`

Comment: @Florian - It was a good suggestion, but it did not work :)

Comment: Did you try to use `get` ? `<div *ngFor="let section of saveForm.get('sections')?.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">`

Comment: @Florian - The error just changes. Instead it says "Identifier 'controls' is not defined. 'AbstractControl' does not contain such a member Angular"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Florian almost got it right, the correct syntax would be:

```
<div *ngFor="let section of saveForm.get('sections')['controls']; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

That way the error/warning goes away and the component still works as expected.